# windows azure Host OS restart crashing iis and task scheduler configuration

Tags: php, windows, azure

I have a php cgi running on my iis and a task scheduler to run a php job. Every time that azure restart Host OS my php cgi and the job i configured crash. What i need to do is set the path to cgi again on iis e recreate the job on task scheduler. I've already read a lot in the internet but couldn't find the problem. What could the problem be?

Comment: Do you have any logs for the crash? Without any additional details, it might be hard to help.

Comment: Also, what specific feature of azure are you using? Websites? Cloud Services? VMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, maybe the path of your PHP CGI and job scripts you set was in the `D:/` disk.

As All virtual machines in Azure are configured with at least two disks when you create the virtual machine – one is an operating system disk and the other is a temporary local disk which is labeled as the D: drive.

The data on these temporary disks may not remain through standard VM lifecycle events. This is because the data for the temporary disks is stored on the host operating system running the hypervisor software while the data for persistent disks is stored in Microsoft Azure Storage.

If you want to keep the files for a long time, you can add a **data disk** to a VM.

For more information. We can see [About disks and VHDs for virtual machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-disks-vhds/) and [Virtual Machines Best Practices: Single VMs, Temporary Storage and Uploaded Disks](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/virtual-machines-best-practices-single-vms-temporary-storage-and-uploaded-disks/)

Otherwise, Azure Web Apps now has provided customers to configure custom PHP runtime and upload scripts as web jobs which can run background scheduled or continuous. If not have to be host on VM, we can migrate the project to Azure Web Apps Serve.

If you have any concerns, please feel free to let me know.